# How to use C static libraries in D?

Tags: linker, static-libraries, d

I'm completely stumped on how to get FreeType 2.4.8 compiled as a static lib and usable from within my D application in Windows. I've tried running it over with objconv, coff2omf, and trying `extern(C)`/`extern(System)`, etc. but nothing seems to work. I'm getting symbol not found errors, access violations and just a bunch of unhelpful errors.

How can I work around this? Am I correct in using `pragma lib` to link to my static libraries, and how do I reliably convert COFF static libs to OMF which DMD/Optlink can use?

**EDIT:** Some examples of what I've tried doing:

1. Compiling the FreeType source with VS 2010 as a static lib, linking in my D code with pragma lib. (Returned a "library format unknown" type error)
2. Same as above, but converting to OMF format using [objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) and then trying to link with pragma lib. (Linked successfully, but still not able to call functions.)
3. Compiled a DLL of the FreeType source, ran it through implib to create an import library, tried linking with pragma lib. (Linked successfully, but unable to to call any functions due to "attempt to privileged function" or "access violation" errors)
4. I've tried defining function prototypes as all of: extern(System), extern(C), and extern(Windows). The first and third mangle the functions names of the extern-ed functions such that they don't match the static libraries, and the second compiles, but I get access violations during runtime when I actually try and call the functions.

I'm able to get it working via dynamic libraries and symbol loading, but I'd much prefer to not require a bunch of external dependencies when deploying my project.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example of what you've tried? e.g. one function prototype declared with example program demonstrating the errors you are getting. Also, if you show us what you have tried with the static lib (attempts to convert it from COFF to OMF) then that would help too.

Comment: Certainly, let me whip some examples up.

Comment: Static libs on Windows *can* be a PITA. Easiest approach is to always use dynamic libraries + implib. Does the created dll work if you use it from C++? If yes, can you show your C++ and D code?
Note that extern(System) means extern(Windows) on Windows and extern(C) on Linux.

Comment: If you build a static FreeType library, you simply just add it to the list of your SOURCE files. Example: `dmd file1.d file2.d C:/dev/proj/freetype.lib`

Comment: @DejanLekic: Good luck with that. The GDC binary requires "libcloog-0.dll", which is nowhere to be found in the 4.5.2 TDM bundle installer. Not to mention that half the links to individual packages on the TDM page are dead.

Comment: @AndrejM.: I use "normal" GCC bundle, not TDM's which contains numerous patches. Seems that TDM enabled cloog there. If i was you, I would remove TDM's bundle, and download gcc from MinGW's website (actually it is on SourceForge).

Comment: Are you talking about D1 or D2? The D2 GDC was built with TDM. https://bitbucket.org/goshawk/gdc/downloads I guess I might try it with MinGW though, if that works.

Comment: I've tried MinGW and I get the same libcloog error.

Comment: The problem was the 4.5.2 installer actually installs the 4.6.1 binaries. Silly online installers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Derelict2 has FreeType bindings: http://www.dsource.org/projects/derelict (See DerelictFT).

Comment: Yes, but they use dynamic libraries, and the version of FreeType they use is quite outdated (2.3.5 I believe, and FreeType is currently at 2.4.8).

Comment: It seems you're right, it is old. There was an ancient FreeType binding that's still here: http://www.dsource.org/projects/bindings/browser/trunk/freetype So OP could take a look at how they used the DLL. Statically linking is probably going to be difficult since DMD uses OMF. The most reliable way to do that is to compile FreeType via DMC. Maybe that's even possible.

Otherwise the OP could show the code he's using so we know if the problem is in the DLL or the calling code.

Comment: Or, forget using the DMD on Windows and use the GDC compiler?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will need extern(System) in your .d files with FT function declarations.
Static library a collection of object files. So no need for any kind of conversion (omf2coff, etc). DMD accepts a static libraries as arguments, so simple `dmd file1.d file2.d C:/path/to/freetype.lib` should work.

#### Edit:

I was wrong. Apparently I needed to read some documentation about the [COFF2OMF](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/coff2omf.html).
**Quote:** *The Microsoft COFF format apparently changed with Visual C++ 6.0. To use coff2omf on a .lib file with the newer format, use Microsoft's linker to convert the file to the earlier COFF format*:

```
link /lib /convert freetype.lib
```

So, judging by the statement above you need to perform 2 steps.

1. First use the Microsoft's linker to convert static library you made with the VisualStudio (in COFF format) to the *old* COFF format as described above.
2. Now execute `coff2omf freetype.lib` to convert the static library into the OMF format.
3. It should now be ready to be used with the DMD the way described originally in my post.

Comment: He says in the OP that he gets a "library format unknown" error when trying to link.

Comment: Wrong, he compiled with VS and thus got a COFF library while dmd only accepts the crappy OMF format.

Comment: Fair enough, I did not do Windows programming in ages... It is about time I start doing that again. :) Thanks for input guys.

Comment: How would I obtain a copy of that Microsoft LINK utility?

Comment: LINK is the linker. It must be part of any Microsoft(R) Visual C++(TM) distribution. It should also be part of the PSDK.

Comment: @DejanLekic The OP did say he compiled FreeType with VS2010 which has to come with a linker -- wouldn't that one work? He should find it in the `/bin` subdirectory of where he installed vs2010.

Comment: It seems that the command:

`link /lib /convert freetype.lib`

doesn't work on MSVC++ 2010's LINK executable (there's no /convert option switch, apparently). Do I have to use an older version?